# .net 6 Ajax POST Large array results in null parameter

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have built a .net 6 MVC Application which needs to process some data passed from the UI in the form of a table of strings (actually JSON objects but I tried simplifying as much as I could to narrow it down).

Here's my Controller Method:

```cpp
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadData( List<string> inputData)
{
    var success = db.ProcessData(inputData);

    return Json(new
    {
        Success = success
    });

}
```

And here is my Javascript call:

```js
var inputData = [];

$.each(tableData.body, function (index, item) {
    inputData.push(JSON.stringify(jQuery.parseJSON(item[0])));
});

var data = {
    inputData: inputData
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "myController")',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
                                
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function(response) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

What happens is that it all works fine as long as my array is not too big (I've tried with a few entries and it works), but when I try it with real data (content length is 226601, so not that impressive), the inputData in my controller is null.
There is not exception, just the data is nulled.

I encounter this when I debug it in VS2022 with IISExpress.
I tried setting some content size limit by adding a web.config file at the root of my project, and I also tried setting MaxRequestBodySize in my Program.cs, but so far nothing has worked.

Is anyone familiar with this ?

EDIT:
I just tried to do JSON.Stringify on my array before passing it, and changing the parameter type to string instead of List. Then I'm able to parse it as an array using JArray.Parse(inputData), and all the data seems to be there. Is there a limit to the size of an array you can post ?

Comment: You can have an error inside of your large json. Try to create a large special json file for test that will consist from  many the  same tested part.

Comment: @Serge The original array has 1486 entries. When I'm testing with a smaller array, I'm just passing the first few entries instead of all. It fails as soon as I take more than (roughly) 1000 items.

Comment: Create  2000 items array. Just copy first 1000 items twice.

Comment: @Serge I created an array with only the first item copied n number of times. It works as long as n is 1024 or under. I tried just creating an array with 1025 times "Hello", and I get a null parameter, but it works if there are only 1024 items, so it's really an array size issue. Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: No, 1024 sounds good for me. You should tell me immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to get data as one raw object

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadData( JArray inputData)
{
var data=inputData.ToObject<List<string>>();
}
```

or  if it is possible you can serialize array twice and send it as a string

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadData( string inputData)
{
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(inputData);
}
```

another way is to search SO and find  how you can increase array size from 1024  to more.

Comment: Yes, Serializing the array and then deserializing it in the Controller works.
I'm not sure I understand what you're saying though: I didn't find anything about a hard 1024 item limit, can you expand on this a bit more ?